# Counting the number of hits to my webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have developed a webpage for the internal monitoring of some services of my company. We wish to record the number of hits on the page and display it real time. I have gone through the questions :

[Determine how many times webpage has been accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273358/determine-how-many-times-webpage-has-been-accessed)

[How can I count the number of the visitors on my website using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610985/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-the-visitors-on-my-website-using-javascript)

But I can't use google analytics and other such tools. I am hoping it can be done in nodejs. The problem is if I do something like this on nodejs server :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var userCount = 0;
app.post('/counterIncrement', function(req, res){
console.log("I received a request to refresh the counter");
userCount = userCount + 1;
res.json({countNum: userCount});
});
var router1 = require('./public/routes/Route1');
router1(app);

var router2 = require('./public/routes/Route2');
router2(app);

var router3 = require('./public/routes/Route3');
router3(app);

var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

app.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, function() {

   console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url); 
});
```

And everytime someone visits our webpage, we send a request from controller to server to increase the counter. Would this not create a race condition when multiple people access the webpage at the same time? Is there some other way possible?

We had a look at cookies also, but we want to increase the counter even when the same user visits again, and even if thats possible, I am unable to understand how the race condition can be avoided?

Comment: insert user Ip address or mac id of computer when u will need count.Count those inserted records.Inserting mac id u can also count unique visitor on your website

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming You're running a single Node.js process then you can be sure that there'll be no race conditions. Node.js is single threaded and hence all the javascript code is executed synchronously. So each request will run your controller method one at a time.

One drawback of this approach would be that your `userCount` would be lost as soon as you restart your server as its stored in the process' memory.

However if you're using more than one Node.js process then this method would fail as each Node.js process will maintain its own different `userCount`. The only fail proof way then would be to use a central database (common to all Node.js process) which already handles race conditions (Most do) and store the count there.

Comment: I think I have a single node.js process(I have edited my code in the question). As in I have a single server.js file with the following code - different calls are made to different routes depending on different actions by end user, but this is the main server file. Is this what you mean by single process?

Comment: Yes you have a single Node.js process. There can be multiple Node.js process when you use the cluster module or use some kind of load balancing to balance load to multiple servers or ports. Basically multiple Node.js process means that you run your process on more than 1 machine or more than 1 port simultaneously and then balance the incoming requests to all the running processes.

Answer (score 2):

> We wish to record the number of hits on the page and display it real
>   time

In that case, use WebSockets for real time, which seems a more convenient solution in your case. With WebSockets, when someone closes the page, you can decrement the number of "live" users as well. You don't even need to store the number in the database, unless you want to keep track of every page hit.

The `userCount` trick you're doing is interesting, but also has a dark side: if the server restarts, you lose the number.

**UPDATE:**

Here's how you do it:

1. When you receive a page hit, you open a WebSocket connection.
2. On opening the connection successfully, increment the live number counter.
3. On opening the connection successfully, increment a number in the database to keep track of all hits.
4. (Optional) On closing a connection, decrement the live number counter.

Comment: Is it also possible to record the number of all hits or only live users? We need to keep a counter of all hits. And how would we be able to not lose the number here when the server restarts?