# Server sent response but Client not loading the sent content

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, browser

I have simple node server **(nodejs + express + ejs rendering)**, when user tried to load a particular page server sends that compiled html and sends that in response.

**In order to track users I have added 2 counters**

a. counter which increments when server receives request for that page

b. when client loads the page it contains one some code which will make HTTP requests back to my server which I use as counter

Now the issue is that as time passes on the difference between `sentResponse` counter and `clientLoad` counter increases increases so much so that I get `sentResponse = 7000` and `clientLoad = 3600`.

Any suggesstions on what could cause that kind of behavior

Note: I also have setup Cloudfare before requests reaches my server and I paused it but still I was getting huge differences ?

Note: I also noticed that lots of users are making requests to the page frequently like multiple times under 4s but I am sure that I am sending valid html and I different is almost 50% so I dont think that every user that visits the page is pressing ctrl+r 2 or more times under 4s.

**Code:**

**server.js**

```
app.get('/dashboard', (res, res) => {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    Tracker.incrementCount('sentResponse');
    res.render(page.ejs, {...});
});

app.get('/client-load-start', (req, res) => {
    Tracker.incrementCount('clientLoadStart');
    res.send(200);
});
```

**page.ejs**

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src='/client-load-start?version=<some_random_4_digit_number>'></script>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        ...
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect this is issue with caching. The browser is caching your page for some xyz amount of time. So during that time if you request the page it will be serve by cache and your server will not receive any hit. Disable caching in your browser and try again.

Comment: @MukeshVerma but if that's the case then server will also not increment the sentResponse count right ? because the page is being loaded from browser's cache so server is not participating in anything, so in that case both sentResponse and clientLoad counters will not get incremented hence they should be almost same, right ?

Comment: See, in case b where when the page is LOADED that will will send http request which will increment a counter at your server. The page is being cached not the request. So whenever page is loaded no matter from it is served from cache or server that http request will be fired on loading which will cause the incremental operation.

Comment: @MukeshVerma
Umm yes so in that case the sentResponse counter will be less than clientLoaded counter right because as server is not sending any response (due to browser caching) the sentResponse will not get incremented but clientLoaded will get incremented regardless of location from where the page was loaded.

But in my case sentResponse is wayyy more than clientLoaded

Comment: If you can share some code I might be able to help.

Comment: @MukeshVerma I have added code to my question

Comment: If you could show me Tracker.incrementCount function it will be helpful. Since you are using EJS templating, why don't you try disabling the template caching by ejs. Something like this EJS.config({cache: false});

Comment: @MukeshVerma I have done that already so I am using nocache npm package for that, and for incrementCount function its simple mongodb query for incrementing a field Trackers.update({type: 'sentResponses'}, { value: {$inc: 1} })

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following possibilities on why the count could be different.

- Setting caching headers (Cache-Control) could cause the browser to cache requests.
- JS is not enabled in client's browser and so there is no possibility in making an AJAX call to the server to update clientLoad counter (This is less possible , but still is one of the possibility).
- People interacted with the page even before the page loaded causing the AJAX call to not fire. People reloaded the page before the page could load.

If you are simply looking to track

- Page hits , you can use the "sentResponse" counter.
- Active Users , think about web sockets ([Counting the number of hits to my webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539575/counting-the-number-of-hits-to-my-webpage))

Comment: 1. already in place, I am using no-cache npm package for that
2. yeah I agree it is very unlikely also even if this was the case the sentResponse count would not be approx 50% more than clientLoad
3. not sure why if a user interacts with page it will lead to not running ajax code and yeah in fact people are reloading the page frequently (Read Note#2 in my question)

Comment: 3. It depends on the when the ajax call is requested. For instance if the ajax call is fired only after the entire page loads and if the user interacted(clicked on some link in the page and navigate away) with the page earlier than the entire page is loaded.

Comment: Regarding your note 2 ,Are you in multi clustered environment where more than one thread could run the same code. If so, you may run into synchronization issue of the counter variables leading to widely varying numbers.  Like I said, there are simpler ways to do what you are looking to do. I would not be too worried about making sure that the responses are actually delivered to the end client by keeping track of request sent and received counters. Node.JS and N/W will make sure the response reaches the user. Could you also talk to what is the purpose of these counters.

Comment: @NISHANTDESAI Can you share the client-load-start script.

Comment: so I'm using 2 techniques for triggering client load start event, 1. <script scr="<api_url>"></script> inside <head></head> section 2. pixel taging, both are nearly same the difference in values between these 2 counters in DB in negligible

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use cache-busting methods. Every time the browser loads `/dashboard` the browser is getting a script source to your `/client-load-start` route. The problem is the only time `/client-load-start` is being requested is when the browser's cache is cleared, or the first time the site loads. This will cause the problem where the two counts can differ greatly over time.

Try to make the browser think `/client-load-start` is a new script that needs to be downloaded. You can do this by adding query parameters to the src.

```
<script src='/client-load-start?<%- Date.now()%>=1'></script>
```

Every time the browser goes to `/dashboard` it'll attempt to download the new script because the query parameters have changed thus busting the cache.

Comment: I have that in place so while compiling EJS template to HTML I am generating a random number and I am attaching it to /client-load-start?version=<%= randomValue %> and then I am sending the final HTML to client, sorry for not mentioning it in my question I'll update it right away

Comment: Try changing the file name completely ``app.get('/client-load-start/:random'`` then in the EJS ``/client-load-start/<%= randomValue %>``. That changes the path completely and will bust anything persistent.

Answer (score 0):

### Sequence of Events

1. Browser requests `/dashboard`
2. Server increases `sentResponse`, renders and sends `page.ejs` to the browser
3. Browser receives `page.ejs` and detects the `<script>` tag
4. Browser checks if the script URL is in the browser cache

   - The sequence ends here if the script URL is found in the cache; `clientLoad` remains unchanged
5. Browser requests script from your server
6. Server executes `get` request, increases `clientLoad`

### Problem

The "problem" here is that the browser - or any proxy between the browser and your server - will cache the returned script unless you instruct it otherwise.

Note that caching is actually expected and intended behaviour in most cases. It’s also the browsers’s default behaviour.

### Solution

To instruct the browser (or proxies) to avoid caching the file, you can set [cache control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

```
app.get('/client-load-start', (req, res) => {
    Tracker.incrementCount('clientLoadStart');
    res
       .set('cache-control', 'max-age=0; private; no-cache')
       .send(200);
});
```

This would instruct the browser to never cache the request and always get a new copy, thus increasing `clientLoadStart` with every request.

Another way is "[cache busting](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting)", meaning you intentionally change the script’s URL, e.g. by appending a random number as you did above, thus "breaking" the cache key.